# TokenStorageInterface return always null

Tags: symfony

I'm injecting "TokenStorageInterface" class in a service.Service is also injecting from a subscriber."TokenStorageInterface" always returning false.I tried inject Security but still returning null.

```
class RestaurantService
{


private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{

    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;

}

public function getRestaurantId():int{

    if($this->tokenStorage->getToken() instanceof User){ // always false
....
```

Usage of RestaurantService

```
class OverridesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

private $restaurantId;

public function __construct(RestaurantService $restaurantService)
 {
    $this->restaurantId = $restaurantService->getRestaurantId();
```

Comment: Tokens are not users.  Typically you would do something like $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()

Comment: @Cerad You are right but $tokenStorage->getToken() always null.Same code working with controller.

Comment: You are using your service in the constructor of a subscriber.  Is this a kernel request subscriber?  If so then the subscriber is being created as part of the bootstrap process.  The security user stuff is also in a subscriber which has not yet been called.  So move the getRestaurantId out of the constructor and into whatever method actually needs the id.  Just a question of timing.